# Something like the wx.MultiChoiceDialog in a panel instead of a dialog

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'd like to use the list (with checkboxes next to each item) that is contained in the wxMultiChoice dialog in a panel.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent to a wx.MultiChoiceDialog is the wx.CheckListBox

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        sampleList = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five',
                      'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven',
                      'more', 'and more']

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.clb = wx.CheckListBox(self, -1, (30,30), wx.DefaultSize, sampleList)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.EvtListBox, self.clb)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKLISTBOX, self.EvtCheckListBox, self.clb)
        self.clb.SetSelection(0)

        sizer.Add(wx.Panel(self), 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.clb, 0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(wx.Panel(self), 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()


    def EvtListBox(self, event):
        pass

    def EvtCheckListBox(self, event):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```